# SQLPlus output not complete

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a SQL script which is bringing back a load of person data from an Oracle database as an XML output.  However it only seems to be bringing back around 2000 rows of the 5000 rows that it should do, it also ends "mid data" which kind of makes me wonder if I'm hitting some character limit or somesuch.

```
Spool c:\person\person_load.xml;

set pages 0
set linesize 150
set long 999999
set head off

Select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('
SELECT DISTINCT 
PERSON.PIN "ContactRef",
PERSON.TITLE "Salutation",
PERSON.FORENAME "Forename",
PERSON.PERSON_SURNAME "Surname",
CASE WHEN PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM IS NULL AND PERSON.HOME_TEL_NUM IS NULL THEN ''0'' ELSE PERSON.HOME_TEL_NUM END "Contact1",
''1'' "Contact1Type" /*HomePhone*/,
PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM "Contact2",
''5'' "Contact2Type" /*Mobile Phone*/,
PERSON.EMAIL_ADDRESS "Contact3",
''6'' "Contact3Type" /*Email*/,
PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM "Contact4",
''10'' "Contact2Type" /*SMSText*/,
CASE WHEN PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM IS NOT NULL THEN ''2'' WHEN     PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM IS NULL AND PERSON.HOME_TEL_NUM IS NOT NULL THEN ''1''     ELSE null END "PreferredContact",
CODE.DESCR || ''; '' || LISTAGG(CODEPSI.DESCR, ''; '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER     BY CODEPSI.DESCR) "Considerations",
PERSON.UPRN "UPRN"
FROM 
PERSON,
RNT_OCCUPANTS,
CODE,
(SELECT DISTINCT PERSON.PIN,
CODE.DESCR
FROM PERSON,
PERSON_SECURE_INFO,
CODE WHERE PERSON.PIN = PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PIN (+) 
AND CODE.CODE = PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PSI_CODE 
AND (CODE.CODE_TYPE = ''PSI'' OR CODE.CODE_TYPE IS NULL) 
AND PERSON_SECURE_INFO.PIN is not null) "CODEPSI" 
WHERE 
PERSON.PIN = RNT_OCCUPANTS.PIN 
AND PERSON.PIN=CODEPSI.PIN (+) 
AND PERSON.WARNING_CODE = CODE.CODE (+) 
AND (CODE.CODE_TYPE = ''WARN'' OR CODE.CODE_TYPE IS NULL) 
AND RNT_OCCUPANTS.PARTY = ''Y'' 
AND RNT_OCCUPANTS.END_DATE_OF_OCCUPANCY is null 
GROUP BY 
PERSON.PIN,
PERSON.TITLE,
PERSON.FORENAME,
PERSON.PERSON_SURNAME,
PERSON.HOME_TEL_NUM,
PERSON.MOBILE_TEL_NUM,
PERSON.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
CODE.DESCR,
PERSON.UPRN 
ORDER BY 
PERSON.PIN') XML from dual;
spool off;
exit;
```

It literally stops mid line...
"< PreferredContact > 1 < / Pre "

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to increase value for your:

```
set long 2000000000
set longchunksize 10000000
```

Comment: Thanks, I increased the SET LONG and it has now returned all data.  Odd as I thought SET LONG was based on the line length?

Comment: @Batad - no, [set long](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088) sets maximum width for displaying BLOB, BFILE, CLOB, LONG, NCLOB and XMLType values, and isn't related to [set linesize](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG085); other than they both default to 80.